# Bold math in Latex within Mathematica

Tags: latex

The new Ctrl-$ functionality for entering Latex code in Mathematica does not appear to allow bold math symbols. I have tried various ways of doing it such as \bm or \mathbf, but with no success.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Which version are you using? It [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qErUt.gif) in 12.3 and 13.0 (both Windows).

Comment: I am using 13.2 on Ubuntu 22.04. It does not work in 13.1 too.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04/v13.2, if you enter ctrl-4 \mathbf{a}+b in an input cell and hit return (not enter), the a is bold. For a text cell, the same command visually doesn't seem to have an effect, however, if you select Cell/Show Expression from the menu (shortcut Shift+ctrl+E), you can examine the box structure. I won't try and paste the whole thing here, but for both cases, you get StyleBox["a", FontSlant -> "Bold"] imbedded in the cell. For b, StyleBox["b", "TI"]. So the \mathbf is having an effect, though it's hard to discern it in a text cell, though it's more distinct in an input cell.

Comment: If I change fonts from the default to Ubuntu, the a is bold in a text cell. So it appears to be related to the specific font being used. Though Bold is being set in the style, the effect is too subtle to see with the default font used for text cells. Try experimenting with different fonts and see if you find an acceptable choice.